# Is there any way to use Countif() without overcounting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### Introduction

I'm using an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter) `=Sum(countif())` to count in a range how many times some keywords appear. My problem is that if in one cell of that range there is more than one keyword, that cell is counted multiple times (once per keyword) and I don't want that.

### Example

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEFJ3.png). From A1 to A7 I have text in each cell. Each cell contains colors. It can be one color such as "Red", or many such as "Red, Green, Blue". I want to calculate how many times "Red", "Green" or "Blue" appear in the range. I tried using the formula `=Sum(countif(A1:A7;{"*"Red*";"*Green*";"*Blue*"}))`, but if a cell contains more than one of these colors, the cell is counted multiple times, and that is not the idea.

[image]

### Question

**Which formula should I use?** In case there is no function or combination of functions to do this, do you know how to create a macro to create the needed formula? I have created some formulas in macros, but all of them simply combined formulas that already existed in excel so that I didn't need to write all the long formulas each time I want to use them and instead I could simply import my shorter formula.

### Notes

- I use "," for decimal punctuation, that is why I separate arrays and functions with ";".
- Feel free to change the title to something more appropriate. I'm not sure how to summarize my problem in a question for the title. If you do so, then remove this note.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm using 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Red","Green","Blue"},A1:A6)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COLUMNS({"Red","Green","Blue"})))^0)>0))
```

Realize that for me `{"Red","Green","Blue"}` creates a horizontal array.  Change the `,` to the delimiter to make it a horizontal array in your local settings.

And, not sure about this one, but in older version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: `ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Red","Green","Blue"},A1:A6))` creates an array that is 3 columns by 6 rows of TRUE/FALSE.  MMULT then multiplies that array with a 1D array with the same number of rows as there are columns in the color array.  Resulting in a 1D array of the count of how many words are found in each cell ie {2,1,2,0,0,2}  We test that it is greater than `0` and sum the results.

Comment: Why do you use "^0" in the formula? If you don't use it, you get {4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}. If you use it, you get {2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}. However, when you compare it with ">0" it gives the same result. Additionally, Why did you use "Sumproduct"? I mean, you are summing an array of 0s and 1s, there is no multiplication. A simple "Sum" would have been enough, as it gives you the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formulas

=SUM(--(MMULT(--(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Red","Green","Blue"},A1:A6))=1),SEQUENCE(3))>0))

In here in the sequence 3 because you have 3 values(Red, Green, Blue) if you have more or less just increase or decrease the sequence

you can also use this one

=COUNT(VALUE(IFERROR(SEARCH({"red"},A1:A6),"")&IFERROR(SEARCH({"blue"},A1:A6),"")&IFERROR(SEARCH({"green"},A1:A6),"")))

[image: Here is the example]

Comment: It would be worth noting that "Sequence()" function is only available to Microsoft 365 subscribers.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90#:~:text=The%20SEQUENCE%20function%20allows%20you%20to%20generate%20a,available%20to%20Microsoft%20365%20subscribers%20in%20Current%20Channel

Comment: That's why I added the second formula. =COUNT(VALUE(IFERROR(SEARCH({"red"},A1:A6),"")&IFERROR(SEARCH({"blue"},A1:A6),"")&IFERROR(SEARCH({"green"},A1:A6),"")))